# write an expression to check if the any of the value in the group is false

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

want to write an expression in an SSRS 2008 textbox to check if any of the value in a field in a group is false.
If false stop and change the background color of the Textbox.

i am trying to do

```
    =iif(field!coloumnname.value="False","Red","silver")
```

The above expression is taking the top most value in the group and giving the output.

I mean if the value is True , it is giving silver background. 
Can anyone help me out

Comment: I think we have to create a loop to check the group but I dont know if we can write the loop in a Textbox.

Comment: What do you mean by "if false stop"? What does your dataset and tablix look like? What is the error you're getting i.e. why isn't your solution working? Note that you can edit your question to add more details (if substantial this will also bump your question for renewed attention).

Comment: The tablix has a group by column on an 'id','name'. when I drill down , it show s me all the records(or courses) that were assigned to that particular 'id' and 'name'. this records also has a boolean value field.                                                            So I have to show an alert[or change background color of the id field] in the Textbox if any of the records have a false boolean record.                                                             id +name    (boolean value)  course_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the min function in the group level background property:

```
=iif(min(Fields!Value.Value, "GroupName") = "False", "Red", "Silver")
```

This should give you the functionality required.