# SSRS expression that evaluates if any string in group matches parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a SSRS report that contains the following `DataSet`.

```
 Foo | Bar
-----------
  1  |  A
  2  |  A
  2  |  B
```

I am displaying this data in a `Tablix`, there is a row grouping on `Foo`.

```
 Foo | Quantity
----------------
[Foo]|[Count(Bar)]
```

The above produces:

```
 Foo | Quantity
----------------
  1  |    1
  2  |    2
```

I also have a string parameter `bar`, when this parameter matches any of the values of `Bar` found in the row group I would like to highlight the Quantity cell.

i.e.

```
=IIf(Fields!Bar.Value = Parameters!bar.Value, "Plum", "Orange")
```

If `bar` is set to 'A', the above expression will provide the desired behavior for Foo = 1, but not Foo = 2.

I saw a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591696/write-an-expression-to-check-if-the-any-of-the-value-in-the-group-is-false) related to booleans, but the solution does not work with strings. Perhaps SSRS has some Any or Contains functionality I'm not familiar with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly....

I think your issue is that you are trying to evaluate each row to see if `Bar` matches your parameter but the cell you want to highlight is an aggregate - its value is based on several rows of data potentially.

You should be able to just get a count of matching rows and if that is greater than zero, then highlight the cell. For example

```
=IIF(
    SUM(IIF(Fields!Bar.Value = Parameters!bar.Value,1,0)) > 0
    , "Plum"
    , "Orange"
    )
```

This just evaluates each row to either 1 or 0 (match or no match), sums the results and if it's greater than 0 (we found a match) then return "Plum"

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution to your problem may be to modify the dataset query to output a new field `Foobar` that concatenates the `Bar` values over the `Foo` grouping.  Using `STRING_AGG` or `FOR XML PATH` such as in the answers [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12023933/10755978), you should be able to get data like the following:

```
 Foo | Bar | Foobar
--------------------
  1  |  A  |   A
  2  |  A  |  A, B
  2  |  B  |  A, B
```

With the data formatted this way, you can use the `.Contains` syntax to check each `Foobar` value for the `bar` parameter.

```
= IIF(Fields!Foobar.Value.Contains(Parameters!bar.Value), "Plum", "Orange")
```

Another option is the `InStr` function.

```
= IIF(InStr(Fields!Foobar.Value, Parameters!bar.Value) > 0, "Plum", "Orange")
```